# How do I connect a machine on the default network to a subnetwork that I have created in Google Cloud Compute?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-vpn

I am trying to create a system of subnetwork within the default network in my GCP.

I have created a vpc network with subnet CIDR (10.142.x.x/28). This subnet's CIDR is within the range of the adresses for that region. i.e `10.142.0.2 to 10.142.15.253` for that region.

However when I try to connect to the machine through another machine on default network. I'm not able to connect to the machines on the subnet.

I am not sure what is happening here? I thought that resources on the default network can always connect to subnets in that region.

Comment: What command are you using and what is the error message? Did you open firewall rules for traffic? Edit your question with details.

Comment: Do you have 2 VPC? The default and the new one? Is your VM is created in the new one?

Comment: So from what I understand I could not connect from default network to a subnet in my own network. But I can connect via some firewall rules 2 machines on different subnets on my explicitly created network. What I really wanted to achieve though is being able to access all subnets from a machine on the default network. Which would act like jumphosts.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yeah so essentially the 2 instances one on default and one on my own network on a subnet. But I can't connect the default network machine to the subnet machine in the same region. By the way while we are at it. It would also be nice to know if there is way I can connect the subnet machine to internet without cloud NAT.

Comment: @dusual, is that [something like this](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/multiple-interfaces-concepts) that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Fist have a look at what [VPC networking documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc) to have a better understanding of the topic at hand.

**In order to connect to machine that's in a different VPC you have a few options;**

- create a bastion VM with two interfaces; one connected to `default` VPC and nic1 to your `subnet` VPC (first SSH to bastion VM and then SSH to target VM) (not super convenient but very secure) ([multiple interface documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/multiple-interfaces-concepts) - it's what Guillaume Blaquiere linked to);
- use [VPC peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering) feature to connect two VPC's (machines from connected networks would be able to communicate with each other, less secure and super convenient);
- [assign static public IP's](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) and use them to connect (not secure because you're exposing VM's on the Internet).

**If you create your subnets in automatic mode then all the routes and firewall rules will be created automatically. In this case all the VM's in the same VPC will be able to communicate (all traffic is allowed).**

If you create your own network with [custom subnet creation mode](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#create-custom-network) please keep in mind that in order to communicate with instances in those subnets you have to create a proper [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#affiliated_resources) (for ssh, rdp) and also create routes to the Internet - otherwise you won't even be able to SSH into VM's in this network if you don't allow it.

Answering your last question from the comment above - you can connect to the Internet without Cloud NAT but even if you reselve public IP to your VM's you still will be using internal IP to communicate through the gateway (there's no possibility to get an external IP on one of VM's interfaces due to security / management reasons).